# SQLiteNetExtensions - NuGet Could not install package

Tags: c#, xamarin, nuget, sqlite-net-extensions

I've been developing several cross platform mobile projects using Xamarin. Pretty much all of them utilize SQLite in some way. I've been maintaining two separate libraries for my SQLite functionality; one for iOS and one for Android. The way I've been doing things has limited how much code I can re-use between my Android and iOS versions of my applications. I would like to consolidate much of my SQLite functionality into a single cross platform library in order to allow further consolidation of code.

The issue that I'm running into is when I try to install `SQLiteNetExtensions`. I seem to only be able to install this on an Android or iOS project, but I cannot install it on a PCL iOS/Android project.

This is the error that I get when I try to install `SQLiteNetExtensions` in the Package Manager Console:

```
Install failed. Rolling back...
Install-Package : Could not install package 'SQLite.Net-PCL 3.0.5'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets 'portable-net45+sl50+MonoAndroid10+xamarinios10+MonoTouch10', but the 
package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.
At line:1 char:1
+ Install-Package SQLiteNetExtensions
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PowerShell.Commands.InstallPackageCommand
```

The type of project I'm trying this on is a C# Portable Class Library. I select that when I create the project, then I select the target frameworks like so:

[image]

Then I right click on References and select Manage NuGet Packages. I enter sqlitenetextensions in the search and I click on Install for SQLite.Net Extensions-PCL. After that I get the error.

This error does NOT occur when I create an Android or iOS library project and attempt the same sqlitenetextension install.

How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the issue is that SQLite.NET PCL is not compatible with Silverlight 5, only 4.

There is a fork here you could try: https://www.nuget.org/packages/SQLite.Net-PCL-Silverlight/  It works for me, although I haven't checked against Xamarin.